# Ifstream not retrieving data using array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, fstream, ifstream

I've been trying to read data from employee-info.txt using ifstream and storing it in an array, but it did not read anything.

The main goal of my code is, every time that it was able to read a value in employee-info.txt, It will loop and the integer variable valueChecker will increment by one. After the loop is done, the value of valueChecker will be returned in order to determine how many strings are retrieved from employee-info.txt. Based on the contents of employee-info.txt, it should return an int of 8, but it is only returning an int of 0, which is the initialized value.

I also checked through debugger and  the record array did not read anything from the file. I already checked the address of the file and it is correct.

Here is the code in Employee.h:

```
#pragma once
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

class Employee
{
public:
   struct EmployeeRecord {
     static const int recordSize = 100;
     static const int fieldSize = 4;
     std::string record[recordSize][fieldSize];
   };

public:
   Employee();
   ~Employee();
   int employeeDataChecker();
   void employeeWriteData();
   void employeeDisplayData();
   EmployeeRecord& employeeReturnRecordArray();

private:
   EmployeeRecord emp_record;

};
```

Employee.cpp:

```
#include "Employee.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int Employee::employeeDataChecker()
{
    //Check if there are data in the employee-info.txt
    EmployeeRecord emp;
    int valueChecker = 0;
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("C:\\Users\\RJ\\Desktop\\employee-info.txt");
    for (int index = 0; index < emp.recordSize; index++) {
        for (int index2 = 0; index2 < emp.fieldSize; index2++) {
            while (inFile >> emp.record[index][index2]) {
                valueChecker++;
            }
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
    return valueChecker;
}
```

employee-info.txt:

```
     ID           Firstname            Lastname                 Sales
      1                 Joe            Satriani             500000.00
```

Comment: check that the file opens correctly using `inFile.good()`

Comment: Shouldn't you assign `emp` to `emp_record`, or completely ditch this local object? Anyway, it's weird to have a function named `employeeDataChecker` opening a file and modifying the object.

Comment: Um... `while (inFile >> emp.record[index][index2])` ? with no adjustments or checks to `index`, `index2`, that thing will drive to the end of the file. I.e. the for loops outside are worthless. Dare I ask why there is a `while` there ? For for that matter, why there isn't *only* a line counter? A simple instrumented dump to stdout in there should assist in explaining why `valueChecker` remains zero regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, first, you have to check if file is correctly opened (i.e. inFile.is_open()).

Then, forget iteration on fields and try to do something like this:

```
int id;
char firstname[64] = { 0 };
char lastname[64] = { 0 };
float sales;

inFile >> id;
inFile.get(firstname, 64, ' ');
inFile.get(lastname, 64, ' ');
inFile >> sales;
```

On failure, [inFile >>] operator could return false and then it wont increment valueChecker.